# Selenium WebDriver - eCLIPSE - Pop-Up Handling - "No Alert" Exception Error

Tags: eclipse, selenium, popupwindow

in eclipse, have tried to handle pop-up window shown in the same website in below 2 methods.
(1) using code Flip.switchTo().frame("loginIframe");
(2) using Alert Good = Flip.switchTo().alert();

Flip refers to webdriver, loginframe refers to the frame id of the pop-up window, Good refers to Alert reference.

below are the steps am trying to automate
1) open google browser
2) enter https://www.snapdeal.com/
3) click on Sign-in
4) click on Login
5) Login pop-window is shown
6) Click on X icon at the top right corner to close the window.

method 2 failed at step 5 & 6

Website -https://www.snapdeal.com/ shows the pop-up window and observed that method 1 is working but not method 2 and getting org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: no alert open

wonder how same pop-up window belongs to same website is passing in method 1 but failing method 2.

please help.

below is the code

```
package basic;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;

public class FlipKart{

    public static void main(String[]args) throws InterruptedException{

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\hp\\workspace\\Selenium\\browser\\chromedriver.exe"); 
    WebDriver Flip = new ChromeDriver();
    Flip.get("https://www.snapdeal.com/");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    Flip.manage().window().maximize();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    Flip.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sdHeader']/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/span[1]")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    Flip.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sdHeader']/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/span[2]/a")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);

 // METHOD 1 - WORKING GOOD
    //Flip.switchTo().frame("loginIframe");
    //Flip.findElement(By.id("checkUser")).click();
    //Thread.sleep(1000);
    //Flip.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='close-pop']/i")).click();

  //METHOD 2 - GETTING EXCEPTION ERROR
    Alert Good = Flip.switchTo().alert();
    Good.dismiss();

    }

}
```

Comment: driver.switchtoalert; driver.close; can you check this?

Answer (score 0):

dismiss() is basically used to click on the 'Cancel' button of the alert. Since, there is no 'Cancel' button, that's why method 2 is failing.

Comment: thanks kapil for your answer, yes there is no Cancel button in pop-up window only X icon. so i guess step 5 is passing only step 6 is failed. so can you advise me how to handle the step 6) Click on X icon at the top right corner to close the window.

Comment: @badri -  Method 1 is not helping you to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.switchTo().alert();
driver.findelement(by.xpath("provide your cross(close)icon path")).click();
```

*1. First switch to your alert 
2. And then perform operation
3. Perform click operation on cross button.*

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

On the website https://www.snapdeal.com/ as you mentioned in your Question `but not method 2 and getting org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: no alert open` is the correct behavior.

The reason is, if you take a closer look at the elements like the `Mobile Number/ Email` field on the popup through `Development Tools`, you will observe those elements are embedded in the **`HTML DOM`** itself within an **`iframe`** tag as `<iframe id="loginIframe" ... >`. So to handle those elements we have to switch to the **`iframe`** first then perform the desired operation of sending the `Mobile Number/ Email` or to `Close` the popup. In your first case as you handled them properly by switching to the **`iframe`** first, so it worked.

In your second case, you have tried to take help of **`Alert`** class as in `Alert Good = Flip.switchTo().alert();` to `Dismiss` the alert as in `Good.dismiss();`. But as there was no `Alert` present in the `HTML DOM` hence you got a **`NoAlertPresentException`** as **`org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: no alert open`**.

Let me know if this Answers your Question.